# Can we setup/map crawled properties with refinable strings in Content Type Hub?

Tags: sharepoint-online, enterprise-search, crawled-property, refiner, content-type-hub

We have created a Search Center Site (Classic SharePoint) using the **Enterprise Search Template**. We have 80+ sites (SharePoint Online - Modern Team Sites) from where I have to show data in the classic search site.

We want to implement the refiners and advanced search page on the search center site. We have created all *Sites Columns* and *Content Types* in **Content Type Hub** and these site columns and content types are being used in all 80+ sites.

I have a question -

> Will we need to set-up/map the crawled properties to the refinable
> string in each site collection (80+ sites) separately OR can we setup only in the Content Type Hub site collection so that we can avoid setting sep in 80+ sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map crawled properties with refinable string in one site collection. Go to site settings --> Search Configuration Export, it will download SearchConfiguaration.xml. Now upload this xml in all other site collections using import option in the site settings like below

[image]

We can't create Refinable Managed Properties at content type hub level and publish across all Site Collection

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set it up once in the SharePoint Search schema, then it will propagate to all sites so to speak.

So what you would do if you have a column A and want to map it to a managed property that can be used in search center and for all sites is:

1. Ensure that column A has a crawled property by creating an item/document with the column filled out and optionally re-index the list/library through list/library settings --> advanced --> reindex this list.
2. Go to the SharePoint search admin page on https://{domain}-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/searchadmin/TA_SearchAdministration.aspx and click on Manage Search Schema
3. Click on crawled properties and search for Column A (search for internal name), click on the crawled property and map it to a managed property (eg. a refinable string).

You can now use the managed property in your search queries and it will work across all sites consuming the content type/field.